# Devops - Deploying war to tomcat and accessing it as container

Tags: docker, tomcat, devops

My Jenkins job is able to build the code and generate two war files and copy it to remote Docker host. It is also able to build the image of tomcat container with two wars deployed into it. Docker Container is also launching up.

But I see that deployed war files aren't exploded into folders inside `tomcat/webapps`. So, Tomcat is accessible from outside, but application is not .

How Can I fix this?   Why aren't war's exploding?

Dockerfile content below,

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8
MAINTAINER admin

COPY /App-UI.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY /App-Backend.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Comment: did you find any error in `catalina.logs`?

Comment: Yes...It pointed me to the culprit. There was a missing bean dependency. Thanks for the hint